# permission denied to user/repo for user

Tags: git, github

I installed git through `sudo apt install git`. Then I set my git config `git config --global user.name "<usermame>"` and `git config --global user.email "<email@email.com>"`

I created a public repository under `<username>` and cloned it to my local machine using HTTPS.

I made a tiny change in my repo (editing the README.md) and proceed to commit. When I try to push it, I got

`remote: Permission to <username>/<publicrepo>.git denied to <username>.`

`fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/<username>/<repo>.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403`

I used the correct username, and the correct personal token. I am running on Ubuntu 20.04

How can it be possible for you to be denied to your own public repository?

Comment: `user.name` is your personal name.  [It has nothing to do with authentication.](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#user-name).

Comment: This, incidentally, is one of many reasons I prefer to use ssh instead of https here. There's still an authentication issue, but since ssh authentication is part of ssh itself, you can test it easily outside of Git. With github.com in particular you just run `ssh -Tvvv git@github.com` to observe what's being sent for authentication, and what GitHub think of the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check first what `git config credential.helper` returns, just in case it somehow caches the wrong credentials

It it returns `xxx` (replace '`xxx`' by the actual returned value), try:

```
printf "protocol=https\nsite=github.com"|git-credential-xxx get
# and
printf "protocol=https\nsite=github.com"|git-credential-xxx erase
```

Comment: hi sorry for the late response. I was away for a week or so. Running git config credential.helper on my terminal returns nothing. What happened here?

Comment: @adena What is your OS (Linux I suppose, but which one), OS version, git version?

Comment: Hi guys thanks a lot for the response, I found the reason. I forgot to tick the boxes when creating the api key that gives me permission to push! Stupid silly mistake! THANKS!